# Как элементы массива превратить в ссылки, которые добавляют себя в GET запрос?

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, по GET запросу идет в нужную папку и выводит список содержимого этой папки. 
Например, такая ссылка **index.php?url=files** выводит на страницу список содержимого папки "**files**"  
Как превратить список содержимого в ссылки, при нажатии которых, они добавятся в эту же GET переменную? 
Например, набираю **index.php?url=files** и в папке есть подпапка test и она вывелась в списке. Нажимаю ее и url превращается в **index.php?url=files/test** и на странице показывается содержимое папки test 
Вот скрипт, который читает что находится в папке:

```
<?php
$uri = $_GET['url'];
echo "<b>Список файлов:</b> " .'<br>';
$path = scandir("$uri");
    foreach($path as $k){
            echo $k."<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляем разметку в код

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($path as $k){
    echo "<li><a href='index.php?url=" . $uri . "/" . $k. "'>" . $k . "</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

И, вуаля, у нас есть ссылки.